# Difference of Azure Deployment Environments and Azure DevTest Lab

Tags: azure

for me sometimes, the number of Azure Services, is overwhelming. What is really annoying is that you can't find two lines of description, which explains the concrete uses cases for the different Azure Service.

So does someone know the difference between Azure Deployment Environments and Azure DevTest Lab? Does someone have concrete use cases for this two Azure Services?

Cheers,
Chico

Answer (score 0):

> **Azure Deployment Environments** empowers development teams to quickly and easily spin up app infrastructure with project-based templates that establish consistency and best practices while maximizing security. This on-demand access to secure environments accelerates the stages of the software development lifecycle in a compliant and cost-efficient way.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/deployment-environments/overview-what-is-azure-deployment-environments

and

> **Azure DevTest Labs** is a service for easily creating, using, and managing infrastructure-as-a-service (IaaS) virtual machines (VMs) and platform-as-a-service (PaaS) environments in labs. Labs offer preconfigured bases and artifacts for creating VMs, and Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates for creating environments like Azure Web Apps or SharePoint farms.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-overview

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi SoySolisCarlos,

thank your for your feedback. Unfortunately I can't still grasp both Resources really. Maybe you can give me some use cases in which you would prefer the one or the other azure service and why?

Cheers,
Chico

Comment: Can you tell me what your requirement is?? and I will do my best to provide you with the best option.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have any. I have just read about this two services and want to simply understand in which use case you favor the one or the other?

For which kind of problems, use cases or challenges are this services designed for?